# Common CSS bug: display-inline with weird space

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have some problems.

This is because I wanted to change from floating to `display: inline-block;`

And my results in [this preview](http://jsbin.com/agotiv/2)

Now I notice this strange space above my `<nav>`

If you can't see the strange space look at [this preview](http://jsbin.com/agotiv/4/).

This strange space is not visible when I use float. 
But I am against floating for design, I only want to use float for images.

So my question: **How do I remove that space?**

If anyone know the cure/fix ;) Thanks!

Comment: The strange space is the white area?

Comment: In the white block you see there is some space above the nav. So the nav is magical pushed down..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline flow is fairly tricky thing to get right; it helps to understand how `vertical-align` and `line-height` fit together and how they affect it. In this case, one way of fixing this is with `vertical-align: top` on the `nav` (it being shorter than the `h1`—apply to both if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

It's a space character. Because inline-blocks work the same way as blocks, when you have space characters between them they will have visible delimiter.

To understand it easier look at this example:

```
<p>
This
words
will
have
a
space
between
them
</p>
```

So because you have your items on separate lines in code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a title="home" href="/">home</a></li>
    <li><a title="login" href="/login">login</a></li>
</ul>
```

...browser is adding space in the place of new lines. You have few ways to fix it.

Place them on one line:

```
<ul>
    <li><a title="home" href="/">home</a></li><li><a title="login" href="/login">login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or set `font-size: 0;` on ul and then normal font-size on li. This way space between li's will be equal to 0.

Comment: No spaces found. But thanks for your help. Chris helped met noticing the vertical-align.

Comment: Inline-block elements do not behave the same as block elements:  whitespace is irrelevant between block elements, it only matters for inline elements.  Modifying the font-size is a terrible way to deal with undesirable whitespace since some browsers enforce a minimum font-size and it doesn't play nicely with relative font-sizes (if you're still using px font-sizes, you're doing it wrong).